# Tara was born out of sati to eliminate which of the demon(s)?

Tags: vishnu, tara, sati

I have heard about Sati's 10 forms known as mahavidhyas.
The second one, known as **Tara** is one of the most prominent forms of Goddess Sati, and I had read somewhere had incarnated to slay demon Hayagreeva.
Is that right? Kindly enlighten me more.
I know hayagreeva was an incarnation of Lord vishnu.
And he himself killed madhu kaitabh right?
Kindly enlighten me more on this.
Thank you.

Ref:
[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara_(Mahavidya)#:~:text=Khadaga%2C%20flaying%20knife,tantric%20manifestations%20of%20the%20goddess](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tara_(Mahavidya)#:%7E:text=Khadaga%2C%20flaying%20knife,tantric%20manifestations%20of%20the%20goddess).